# Run app as admin in Mountain Lion

Tags: macos

I have an app which has to be run as an admin on Mountain Lion. This app is NOT installed on the system. The user Does NOT want to open the terminal and run sudo /xyzlocation/Myapp.

The idea is the user will click on the App. The App launches and then the App opens terminal where the user can key in the password.The App will then continue running. The user is the admin on the system.

Also not sure if it makes a difference but XQuartz or X11 is not present on the user's machine.

Answer (score 1):

What if you wrote a script with the sudo that they could double-click? You could also modify the sudoers file to not need the password.

AppleScript could do this too, including a standard OSX popup for the password.